# Bootstrap4- sticky first row and column for grid/flex layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

can anyone give me an idea of how to approach the attached grid/table layout using bootstrap4 flex/grid (must be responsive)?
It's like a table with sticky first row and sticky first column as navigation items.

I tried using w- & h- but it's not responsive without media query. Would like to know the best solution on bootstrap4.

[image]

Thanks a lot! :)

(Pardon my English...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Freeze First Row & First Column**

However, to get this behavior for both first row and first column, you need to separate the first row, first column, and first cell from the table, and then continuously set the position of these elements based on the scrolled position of the table body, upon a scroll event.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('tbody').scroll(function(e) { 
        $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft());
        $('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()-5); 
        $('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()-5); 
      });
    });
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    th, td {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: white
    }
    table {
      position: relative;
      width: 400px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    thead {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 400px;
      overflow: visible;
    }
    thead th {
      min-width: 80px;
      height: 40px;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(1) {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      height: 40px;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    tbody {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 400px;
      height: 90px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    tbody td {
      min-width: 80px;
    }
    tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Tanggal</th>
          <th>Judul Pekerjaan</th>
          <th>Deskripsi</th>
          <th>Level</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Severity</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1 May 2017</td>
          <td>Satu</td>
          <td>Satu</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Lorem</td>
          <td>Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2 May 2017</td>
          <td>Dua</td>
          <td>Dua</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3 May 2017</td>
          <td>Tiga</td>
          <td>Tiga</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3 May 2017</td>
          <td>Tiga</td>
          <td>Tiga</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2 May 2017</td>
          <td>Dua</td>
          <td>Dua</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3 May 2017</td>
          <td>Tiga</td>
          <td>Tiga</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3 May 2017</td>
          <td>Tiga</td>
          <td>Tiga</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```